# Change phone icon of lightning-clickToDial in LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

Is there a way to change the phone icon which gets displayed in lightning-clickToDial element to any other icon?
By default it shows an 'end call' icon. I want to change that icon to a normal phone icon. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code snippets from salesforce component library.

**Component:**

```
<lightning:clickToDialService aura:id="clickToDialService"/>

<lightning:button label="enableClickToDial" onclick="{! c.enableClickToDial }"/>
<lightning:button label="disableClickToDial" onclick="{! c.disableClickToDial }"/>
<lightning:button label="onClickToDial" onclick="{! c.onClickToDial }"/>
<p><lightning:clickToDial value="14155555554"/></p>
<p><lightning:clickToDial value="14155555555" recordId="5003000000D8cuI" params="accountSid=xxx, sourceId=xxx, apiVersion=123"/></p>
```

**JS Controller:**

```
({
    enableClickToDial: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        // clickToDialService is for internal use only.
        // Use sforce.opencti.enableClickToDial() in your org.
        // https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_enableclicktodial_lex.htm
        var clickToDialService = cmp.find("clickToDialService");
        clickToDialService.enable();
    },

    disableClickToDial: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        // clickToDialService is for internal use only.
        // Use sforce.opencti.disableClickToDial() in your org.
        // https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_disableclicktodial_lex.htm
        var clickToDialService = cmp.find("clickToDialService");
        clickToDialService.disable();
    },

    onClickToDial: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        // clickToDialService is for internal use only.
        // Use sforce.opencti.onClickToDial() in your org.
        // https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_cti.meta/api_cti/sforce_api_cti_onclicktodial_lex.htm
        var clickToDialService = cmp.find("clickToDialService");
        clickToDialService.addDialListener(function(payload){
            console.log("This alert simulates the onClickToDial method for Open CTI in Lightning Experience. The phone number is dialed sending the following payload: " + JSON.stringify(payload));
        });
    }
});
```

Here is a [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:clickToDial/example) for AURA Components on salesforce component library it will render numbers as shown below

[image]

LWC [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-click-to-dial/example) example is not working so the best thing is to raise a case to salesforce in case you need to use it in LWC.